# lua dkjson get value from json array

Tags: json, lua

```
local json = require ("dkjson")
local obj = {"dogs":[{"photo":"http://example.com/1.jpg","price":20}]}
obj_t = json.decode(obj)
```

I'm use construction: obj_t.dogs.photo  and this return nil

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid Lua code, but if we fix the string (`local obj = [==[{"dogs":[{"photo":"http://example.com/1.jpg","price":20}]}]==]`) then it looks like the problem is that you have a map with an array that has a map in it, so you're missing accessing the array element. You need to use something like `obj_t.dogs[1].photo`.

Comment: I get this object from response api